# Network Manager service assigning already used IP in the network in RHEL7-8

Tags: networking, kernel, rhel7, networkmanager, rhel8

We have been using network-scripts to manage the networking of our Linux systems adding NM_CONTROLLED=no in ifcfg-ethn files. But we have encountered a special case where this is not working and we need to use Network Manager service. I have encountered an issue with it.

Existing system IP - > 192.168.2.4/24

Just for testing I tried to configure the same IP on new system and unfortunately, it did get configured. With network-scripts, we never encountered this. It used to check if the IP has already been assigned but Network Manager is not doing this. Do we have any flag or something in NetworkManager settings to enable so that it checks for existing IP addresses before assigning. I have configured it directly using ifcfg-files, and I also need to use virtual interfaces eth0:1 for our specific use cases.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update 11-08-2021**

[eth0-interface]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9bCw.png

[eth0:1 interface]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mum9.png

10.133.32.251 already exists in the network, so the network manager is correctly ignoring it after executing the suggested command 'nmcli con modify ipv4.dad-timeout 3000'. But eth0 is also ignored and hence no IP is configured on any interface.
Is it an issue or I am making some mistake here, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

configure `ipv4.dad-timeout`, for example `nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" ipv4.dad-timeout 3000`.

Comment: I tried that but now facing another issue. I have eth0 interface as well as eth0:1 virtual interface. Now when eth0:1 has duplicate IP, it is ignoring both eth0 and eth0:1.